# Stop debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Good morning in my timezone.

I am debugging a web application in Eclipse, i am using WAS 6.1, when i reach the bad code behavior i wanted to stop the debugging , the forward code will make a commit in database and i do not want that.But the square red button(stop button) is frozen(not available), in debug perspective or in the console tab. Why is this happening, and how can i stop the debugging.The only solution is to stop the server

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint? Is your code running in several threads? If so, you will need to select the right thread for the stop button to be active.

Answer (score 1):

If the button is disabled you can right-click on the root of stacktrace and click terminate or terminate&remove option.It will end debugging session. 
IBW, I hope you have "Allow remote termination of VM" enabled in the debug configuration.